# Reading logs with the word 'ERROR' between 2 dates

Tags: awk, sed, grep

The logs are in the format:

```
2018-06-25 00:00:20,073 DEBUG SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-26 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-26 17:37:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-26 19:00:20,073 DEBUG SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-27 00:00:20,073 DEBUG SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-28 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-29 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-30 00:00:20,073 DEBUG SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-01 11:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-02 02:00:20,073 DEBUG SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-02 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-03 20:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
```

I want to find and display all the logs between 2 dates (suppose 2018-06-26 to 2018-07-02) which have the word ERROR in it. I am gonna  take the dates in dynamically so they will be variables $FROM and $TO.

Any `grep`, `awk` or `sed` implementation will do

EDIT:
Both the $TO and $FROM dates should be inclusive and might need to access multiple log files so the logs may not be sorted

Comment: Should the errors that occur on $TO be included or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk, using `-v` option to pass shell variables into awk variables:

```
$ awk -v from="$FROM" -v to="$TO" 'from <= $1 && $1 <= to && /ERROR/' log.txt
2018-06-26 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-26 17:37:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-28 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-06-29 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-01 11:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
2018-07-02 00:00:20,073 ERROR SAMPLE TEXT CONTENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK:

`awk  '/'$FROM'/,/'$TO'/ {print $0}' log.txt | grep ERROR`

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/'$FROM'/,/'$TO'/p' log.txt | grep ERROR
```

Comment: Nice one. Works only when the log is sorted by date. This will be the case most of the times, but maybe worth mentioning.

Comment: @RoVo log file will have a date sorted by default.

Comment: Yes. This is what I said. But maybe other people have another use case and think this answer is valid for them too, so it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: This does not include error from the $TO day. @Pratik, is this a problem?

Comment: @SivaPrasath I need look at multiple files and since they are compressed at different times the logs might not always be sorted so I think I need something that work on an unsorted file too

Comment: @glenn yes I will need the logs of the $TO date too

Answer (score 1):

Simple yet effective;

`egrep '2018-06-26|2018-07-02' log file | grep "ERROR"`

Answer (score 0):

Loop the dates ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226229/bash-looping-through-dates)):

```bsh
FROM=2018-06-26
TO=2018-07-02
d=$FROM
while [ $d != $TO ]; do 
  grep "^${d}.*ERROR" logfile
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```